What are fuselage Inserts?
From weight & balance control and loading manual:

Body Station (B.S.) is defined as a manufacturing location on the airplane. For first of an airplane model, B.S. are continuous from the front to the aft of the airplane. For later versions that are either stretched (i.e. fuselage inserts added) or shrunk (i.e. fuselage sections removed), B.S. becomes discontinuous, for manufacturing reasons.


What are fuselage inserts?
Why are Body Stations discontinuous when they are added to the fuselage?


Unrelated to the question, but I can't help seeing your username as "skywaitress"...  Just in case you care about such weird little things.  ;)

Which weight & balance control and loading manual?  Are you referring to the FAA handbook from the USA?


what are fuselage inserts? and why is Body Station discontinuous when they are added to the fuselage?

Body stations ($\small \sf BS$ or $\small \sf STA$) are used to describe the position of the fuselage sections. They correspond to the distance of the fuselage frames from the STA reference point. The reference point varies among designers, for the Boeing 737 NG series it is a point 130.0 inches forward of the airplane nose, and a $\small \sf STA$ number corresponds initially to the distance from this point in inches.

See What is the coordinate system used in an Aircraft?.

The fuselage sections themselves are major aircraft zones, e.g. section $\small \sf 43$ on a 737 NG:

Source: Boeing 737 NG Maintenance Manual
Manufacturers design families of aircraft to suit different passengers or cargo configurations, e.g. the Boeing 737 NG family includes different fuselage lengths for models -600/-700/-800/-900. The fuselages are almost identical except a few sections are adjusted, a.g. section $\small \sf 43$  can be extended by inserting additional segments, the inserts of your question.
For example, the sections of the 737-600 fuselage have $\small \sf STA$ numbers corresponding to actual distances from the reference point. To create a  737-700 fuselage, section $\small \sf 43$ space between $\small \sf {STA \; 500}$ and $\small \sf {STA \; 520}$ (20" long) is extended with stations $\small \sf {STA \; 500A}$ through $\small \sf {STA \; 500D}$ (80" long). This adds 3 windows on each side of the cabin. The corresponding diagram for the 737-700:

Source: Boeing 737 NG Maintenance Manual
The numbering is still monotonic, but numbers beyond $\small \sf {STA \; 500}$ don't correspond anymore to distances from the STA reference point. Thus when checking W&B with loads specified using $\small \sf {STA}$ numbers a conversion table [station ⇄ arm] must be available.

Much obliged....
